How to vertically displace a word in a sentence?
I want to write the word CAR in a text slightly above of the line. How can I do it?
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
I want the word CAR in this line, but a few millimeters above (that is, placed slightly higher when compared with the remaining words in the line).
\end{document} 


Welcome to TeX.SE.

I suggest you employ the \raisebox macro to accomplish your formatting goal. The macro takes two arguments: the desired vertical displacement, and the material to be raised.

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
I want the word \raisebox{2mm}{CAR} in this line, but raised 2 millimeters.
\end{document}

